# Alter table merge columns T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to alter the physical structure of a table.

Combine 2 columns into a single column for the entire table.

E.g

```
ID  Code  Extension
1   012   8067978
```

Should be

```
ID  Num
1   0128067978
```

Comment: You need to create the new column, update its value then drop the old columns if you don't need them anymore.

Comment: It would be good to know why you "need" to alter they structure of the table in the way you suggest. Concatenation such as this can go against the principals of normalisation, especially if you later need to unconcatenate for whatever reason. Consider along with the above example, the possibility of having a value in the [code] column of 0128 and a value in the [extension] column of 067978. You can end up with the same result from different starting points, and once you've concatenated them, there may be no turning back. There may be other options open to you such as a computed column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add them together in the select statement:

```
SELECT Column1 + Column2 AS 'CombinedColumn' FROM TABLE
```

To Permanently Add them together:

Step 1.  [Add Column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190238.aspx):

```
   ALTER TABLE YOUR_TABLE
     ADD COLUMN Combined_Column_Name VARCHAR(15) NULL
```

Step 2.  Combine fields

```
   UPDATE YOUR_TABLE
     SET Combined_Column_Name = Column1 + Column2
```

If you wanted to keep the table intact you could just access the table information through a [view](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx).

```
CREATE VIEW View_To_Access_Table
AS
   SELECT t.Column1, t.Column2, etc....
           t.CombinedColumn1 + t.CombinedColumn2 AS 'CombinedColumnName'
   FROM YOUR_TABLE t
```

You could also create a [computed column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx) if you didn't want to create a view:

```
ALTER TABLE YOUR_TABLE
  ADD COLUMN CombinedColumn AS Column1 + Column2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE DataTable ADD FullNumber VARCHAR(15) NULL
GO

UPDATE DataTable  SET FullNumber = ISNULL(Column1, '') + ISNULL(Column2, '')
GO

-- you may have FullNumber as NOT NULL, if the number is mandatory and not null for every record
ALTER TABLE DataTable ALTER COLUMN FullNumber VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
```

First step creates the column and the second makes the concatenation of strings, also taking care of null values, if any.

Before dropping old columns, you should consider their usage. If you need any of the numbers in some reports, it is harder to split the string than actually having the value stored. However, this also implies redundancy (more space, possible consistency problems).

Answer (score 0):

You can first combine the column into a single column then perform following steps:-

```
update table Column1 = ISNULL(Column1, '') + ISNULL(Column2, '')
```

rename the column and drop the extra column from table.
make sure that the column have datatype as varchar.